# Dynamically create webcomponent

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

Dears,

I use following code to add custom component dynamically:

```
let newItem = document.createElement("my-item");
this.$.mylist.appendChild(newItem);
```

html adds successfully, and I see constructor(), ready() calls. Unfortunately all html-binding (I mean on-click, on-keyup, on-keydown etc) don't bind. Is any right way to do that? Or probably kind of triggering for initialization inside template()?

Framework: Polymer 3

Comment: try using `addEventListener`.. e.g. `newItem.addEventListener('click', this,_onCLick())`... then `_onClick(){ console.log('triggering'); }`

Comment: I see, but it requires for refactoring

Comment: why do you have to use `createElement`. it can be created as separate tile & import when required. Then it might work.